# Postgresql generate_series dynamic interval

Tags: sql, postgresql, generate-series

Hi I want to make dynamic times series using `generate_series` in Postgresql.

For example, I've got a set of random date list:

```
cleaning date
2015-03-01 00:00
2015-05-31 00:00
2015-06-13 00:00
```

and I want to dynamically split up the date period by these cleaning dates.

The result will be like this:

```
start date         end date
0000-00-00 00:00   2015-03-01 00:00
2015-03-01 00:00   2015-05-31 00:00
2015-05-31 00:00   2015-06-13 00:00
2015-06-13 00:00   (current_timestamp)
```

I've got no idea how I set dynamic interval in `generate_series`...
Is that possible by `generate_series`?

Comment: `0000-00-00 00:00` is an invalid date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really do not see a point of using `generate_series`.

To get result that you proposed you could use `ROW_NUMBER` and self-join:

```
CREATE TABLE tab(cleaning timestamp);

INSERT INTO tab(cleaning)
VALUES ('2015-03-01 00:00'), ('2015-05-31 00:00'), ('2015-06-13 00:00');
```

Main query:

```
WITH cte AS
(
   SELECT cleaning, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY cleaning) AS rn
   FROM tab
)
SELECT COALESCE(c1.cleaning,'0001-01-01'::timestamp) AS start_date,
       COALESCE(c2.cleaning,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AS end_date
FROM cte c1
FULL JOIN cte c2
  ON c1.rn = c2.rn-1
ORDER BY start_date;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/73eae/2/0)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔═══════════════════════════╦═════════════════════════╗
║        start_date         ║        end_date         ║
╠═══════════════════════════╬═════════════════════════╣
║ January, 01 0001 00:00:00 ║ March, 01 2015 00:00:00 ║
║ March,   01 2015 00:00:00 ║ May,   31 2015 00:00:00 ║
║ May,     31 2015 00:00:00 ║ June,  13 2015 00:00:00 ║
║ June,    13 2015 00:00:00 ║ March, 30 2016 11:03:38 ║
╚═══════════════════════════╩═════════════════════════╝
```

**EDIT:**

Another possibility is to use `LAG/LEAD` windowed functions:

```
SELECT COALESCE(LAG(cleaning) OVER(ORDER BY cleaning), '0001-01-01'::timestamp) 
       AS start_date
      ,cleaning AS end_date
FROM tab
UNION ALL
SELECT MAX(cleaning), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
FROM tab
ORDER BY start_date;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo2`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/73eae/3/0)**</kbd>